# Protobuf and exceptions

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, google-style-guide

So I was reading about protobuf exception handling, and I've read the following document:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/IFcZQK0QuzI

> specifically: We don't use exceptions in protobuf as exceptions are
>   disallowed per Google C++ Style Guide:
>   https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Exceptions
>
> As such the code likely won't work if some objects throw.

So, first of all, inside thatsame google style guide, it is mentioned that it is possible to use std::hash, but std::hash is part of the STL which throws! How can it work properly when compiling with -fno-exceptions?
And the same goes for protobuf: it heavily uses std::string for example. How can they claim that they don't throw exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe it *doesn't* work in those circumstances?

Comment: With -fno-exceptions? obviously not, but that's the point. How can they say they are not using exceptions and disallow using object that may throw, but still uses those kind of objects?

Comment: Basically the code contains bugs related to exceptions (such as throwing in code not designed to handle exceptions), but it is "ok" because the style guide says that exceptions are disallowed. In particular, exceptions related to out-of-memory are assumed to not occur in practice. I've never understood the google style guide myself, for exactly the reasons you mention.

Comment: @ByoTic You can safely let the standard library `throw`, as long as either: it doesn't `catch` with your code in between; or the handling of the catch is `std::terminate`

Comment: I believe the protobuf project interprets the style guide as "we will not throw an exception in our library code" rather than we guarantee that no exceptions will ever be thrown when calling our library. The library does call the throwable new operator so an exception can pass through the protobuf library, the question is whether you as a caller of this library support exceptions in your application. if you support exceptions you can catch it, if you don't your application will call std::abort when the exception is thrown.